# Time Machine not properly deleting backups

Tags: backup, time-machine, catalina

I have an issue with Time Machine on macOS Catalina 10.15.6 (and earlier versions of Catalina) that prevents it from properly deleting backups to free up space.

I am backing up to a FreeBSD server that uses ZFS over Samba.  I have also tested using netatalk but saw the same behaviour.

The time machine UI and the `tmutil listbackups` command correctly show backups being deleted but doing `ls` shows several folders from backups that do not appear in the the Time machine UI. These *orphaned* backups don't present a problem until the Time Machine destination runs out of space and is unable to delete backups to free up space. At this point my options are to manually delete the *orphaned* backups from the destination with the `tmutil delete` command or delete the entire backup and start again. I did the latter recently.

Additionally the *orphaned* backups only list the following files:

```
Macintosh HD - Data/ 
Recovery/
```

The *real* backups also how the `Macintosh HD` folder

For example here is the output of of `tmutil listbackups`:

```
$ tmutil listbackups
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-13-103401
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-14-092431
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-15-072542
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-16-083106
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-17-064110
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-18-050256
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-19-035834
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-19-131107
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-19-140703
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-19-155926
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-19-170643
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-19-185950
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-19-200052
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-19-205831
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-19-215711
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-19-232248
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-20-005651
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-20-015636
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-20-025627
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-20-035707
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-20-045717
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-20-055647
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-20-065643
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-20-080414
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-20-090434
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-20-100453
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-20-110119
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-20-121634
/Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000/2020-07-20-130330
```

While here is the output of `ls` in the backup destination:

```
$ ls /Volumes/Time\ Machine\ Backups/Backups.backupdb/HAL-9000 
2020-07-13-103401/
2020-07-13-171911/
2020-07-13-181839/
2020-07-13-191923/
2020-07-13-202839/
2020-07-14-092431/
2020-07-14-142445/
2020-07-14-220404/
2020-07-14-233839/
2020-07-15-033055/
2020-07-15-072542/
2020-07-15-102644/
2020-07-15-113355/
2020-07-15-122717/
2020-07-15-165108/
2020-07-16-083106/
2020-07-16-094313/
2020-07-16-114045/
2020-07-16-131217/
2020-07-16-164541/
2020-07-16-175441/
2020-07-16-213731/
2020-07-17-064110/
2020-07-17-140709/
2020-07-18-000320/
2020-07-18-050256/
2020-07-18-133030/
2020-07-19-035834/
2020-07-19-131107/
2020-07-19-140703/
2020-07-19-155926/
2020-07-19-170643/
2020-07-19-185950/
2020-07-19-200052/
2020-07-19-205831/
2020-07-19-215711/
2020-07-19-232248/
2020-07-20-005651/
2020-07-20-015636/
2020-07-20-025627/
2020-07-20-035707/
2020-07-20-045717/
2020-07-20-055647/
2020-07-20-065643/
2020-07-20-080414/
2020-07-20-090434/
2020-07-20-100453/
2020-07-20-110119/
2020-07-20-121634/
2020-07-20-130330/
Latest@
```

Notice the extra *orphaned* backups in the `ls` command. What is strange is that some backups are properly deleted. For example on most days backups are done hourly, and most are properly deleted. Only a few backups each day become *orphaned*. Those orphans can be deleted with the `tmutil delete` command but Time Machine shouldn't be producing any orphaned backups.

I have no idea why Time Machine is not properly deleting backups.

**Edit:** I have now tested this on a HSF+ formatted USB external hard drive and observed the same behaviour.

Comment: The expected deletions are (or should be) occurring due to TM's own thinning, or manual deletion?

Comment: It *sounds* like @ScruffyDan may have found a bug (not surprised). If those orphaned backups have *any* content I would think they are symlinked to but if they are indeed empty(?)...

Comment: @SteveChambers The orphaned backups do indeed a bunch of content. This is what causes the issues when the destination fills up.

Comment: @benwiggy The deletions should be occurring automatically. all be one backup on any given day should be deleted after 24 hours.